# PHP glob return array with pagination

Tags: php, foreach, thumbnails, glob, pagination

I am using php glob to search a folder for images matching file names and return them in an array. I am not sure how to set a limit on the return and include pagination.

I am currently using the following.

```
    $userpix = $this->_vars['user_username'];

    foreach (glob("./modules/user_gallery/data/{$userpix}_*.*") as $thumb) {
    $resize = preg_replace("/{$userpix}_/", "resize_", $thumb);

    $newstring = substr($thumb, 28);

    echo "<DIV style='float:left;padding:4px '><a href='$thumb' rel='lightbox'><img class='dropshadow' src='./modules/user_gallery/thumbs/grab.php?src=$thumb' width='150' height='100'></a><br /></div>";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add some extra code (pass page parameter from query + compute min/max image id to display), ie.:

```
$userpix = $this->_vars['user_username'];

$page = min(1, (int)$_GET['page']);
$pageSize = 10;
$minId = ($page - 1) * $pageSize;
$maxId = $page * $pageSize - 1;


foreach (glob("./modules/user_gallery/data/{$userpix}_*.*") as $id = $thumb) {
    if ($id < $minId || $id > $maxId) {
       continue;
    }
    $resize = preg_replace("/{$userpix}_/", "resize_", $thumb);

    $newstring = substr($thumb, 28);

echo "<DIV style='float:left;padding:4px '><a href='$thumb' rel='lightbox'><img class='dropshadow' src='./modules/user_gallery/thumbs/grab.php?src=$thumb' width='150' height='100'></a><br /></div>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply zoillek but I seem to be having problem with the foreach in your example. It ends up returning nothing.